# Using String.Split().Contains() on CSV column using Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a database table column that contains a comma separated list of strings. I need to query this table for a string within the comma separated column.

The table:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string sIds { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If the sIds column in my table contains:

```
sIds = "DG,VO,XX,AB"
```

and I execute the following code:

```
string _sId = "AB";

List<MyObject> designParams = _context.DesignParams
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => c.sIds.Split(',').Contains(_sId))
    .Select(c => c)
    .ToList();
```

I get NotSupportedException: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`.

There's a lot of articles similar to my issue, but I haven't been able to find an exact solution. Is there something wrong with my code or is there a different way this should be done?

Comment: show the class-definition of `MyObject` pls

Comment: Why do you even need to Split the string? Why not do a String.Contains on the Ids column ?

Comment: Have you tried without the `.AsNoTracking()`? For me the rest of the code should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Split is not supported by EF. This is because there is no equivalent in SQL.
You can try to define your own function in database like described here: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings.
Or you can try move part of logic from server to client.

Comment: This explains the problem. As a temporary solution, since there's only a couple of dozen records anyway, I stored the results in a variable and then queried the variable using String.Split. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in SQL is "IN", the Contains in LINQ is a bit like reverse:-

```
List<MyObject> designParams = _context.DesignParams
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(c => _sId.Contains(c.sIds))
.Select(c => c)
.ToList();
```